# Deducing the AM-GM inequality from a maximum argument

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $f: [0, \infty)^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\frac{(x_1x_2...x_n)^\frac{1}{n+1}}{1+x_1+...+x_n}$$

Show that the function achieves its global maximum at $(1,1,...,1) \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and deduce that

For all $y_1, ... , y_{n+1} \in [0, \infty)$

$$(y_1...y_{n+1})^\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}y_i$$

---

I have shown that the function's global maximum is at $(1,...,1)$, after that I get that $f(x)\leq \frac{1}{n+1}$, so

$$(x_1x_2...x_n)^\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{n+1}(1+x_1+...+x_n)$$

I fail to see how I can show the proposition for a $n+1$. It seems like I should vary the $1$, but I fail to see how I can achieve the AM GM inequality that way. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Hint: This is AM-GM in the special case where the first number (or the $(n+1)$th number, which seems to suit the indexing here better) is equal to $1$. Can you show the general case from there?

Comment: Just set $x_i = y_i / y_{n+1}$ ...

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot. I suspected it was something trivial (well now it is) that I wasnt seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_1, \ldots, y_{n+1} \in [0, +\infty)$ and assume $y_{n+1} \ne 0$.

Then

\begin{align}
(y_1\ldots y_{n+1})^{\frac1{n+1}} &= y_{n+1}\left(\frac{y_1}{y_{n+1}}\cdots\frac{y_n}{y_{n+1}}\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}\\
&\le y_{n+1} \frac{1 + \frac{y_1}{y_{n+1}} + \cdots + \frac{y_n}{y_{n+1}}}{n+1}\\
&= \frac{y_1 + \cdots + y_n + y_{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{align}